# Floating point rounding error using JSTL formatNumber via curl

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, atg

From Oracle Commerce Platform ATG 11.2, when I hit the JBOSS server I'm getting a different result between a web browser request and curl - it's like the `formatNumber` is disregarded, and values suffer from floating point roundoff errors.

```
<span itemprop="price-currency" content="USD">$</span>

<span itemprop="price" class="selection-price">
    <fmt:formatNumber type="currency"
                      pattern="##0.00;"
                      value="${selectionItem.listPriceAmount}"/>
</span>
```

With 100% consistency, hitting a page in a browser will result in formatted values, such as:

- $27.99
- $20.00
- $10.00

However, an issue was noticed when Google crawled the site, which is 100% reproducible simply via `curl` of the same page.  Those same values appear as:

- $27.990000000000002
- $20.0
- $10.0

There's no user agent logic built-in, just the JSTL `formatNumber`.

Any idea why the exact same path through the exact same JSP would yield different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmt:formatNumber` bypasses `type` and `pattern` attributes when it cannot determine a locale. This is documented in the [**JSTL spec**](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jstl-1.1-mr2-spec-oth-JSpec/):

> If this action fails to determine a formatting locale, it uses `Number.toString()` as the output format.

See section **9.2 Formatting Locale** for how to control locale resolution.

Try setting header `accept-language` when using curl.